# swift: get method list, argument names & types

Tags: swift

I’m trying to figure it out how to work with Objective-C Runtime.

There’s a class that has several methods defined through @objc extension. I want to get list of these methods with argument names and types. Something similar I get using `print(#function, type(of: methodName))` - but this is in case if I call it inside this method, whereas I need to get all this stuff from outside.

I use `class_copyMethodList` and `method_getName`, but I get something like

> method3WithArg1:arg2:

whereas #function and type(of: method) gives

> method3(arg1:arg2:) (Int, Double) -> ()

`method_getNumberOfArguments` gives 2 more arguments, `method_getArgumentType` gives types like q, d, @. Last two I understand, but why q instead of f? (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). 
It would be better to get something familiar like method3(arg1: Int, arg2: Double). Question: do I have to do this manually or there are some other ways?

Further, I want to choose one method from the list, get parameters that it needs, assign that to chosenMethod variable, so that I could call it later. How do I make a closure from Selector? And do I need selectors at all?

Generally, there are some funcs in the class, some will be added later. User is asked to choose method from available, fill the arguments and simply call it.

```
class MyClass {

    var chosenMethod: ((MyStruct) -> ())?

    func execute() {
        chosenMethod?(self)
    }
}

@objc extension MyClass {

    func method0() {
        print(#function, type(of: method0), "\n")
    }

    func method1(_ arg1: String) {
        print(#function, type(of: method1), "\n")
    }

    func method2(_ arg1: Int, _ arg2: Double) {
        print(#function, type(of: method2), "\n")
    }

func method3(arg1: Int, arg2: Double) {
        print(#function, type(of: method3), "\n")
    }
}

//extension MyStruct {
//    @objc(arg1:arg2:) func method4(arg1: Int, arg2: Double) {
//        print(#function, type(of: method4), "\n")
//    }
//}

func getMethods() -> [Selector] {

    var methodCount: UInt32 = 0
    guard let methodList = class_copyMethodList(MyStruct.self, &methodCount) else { return [] }

    var selectors = [Selector]()
    let maxChars = 256
    let ctype = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: maxChars)
    for i in 0 ..< Int(methodCount) {

        let method = methodList[i]
        let selector: Selector = method_getName(method)
        selectors.append(selector)

        print("name: \(String(cString: sel_getName(selector)))")

        let numberOfArguments = method_getNumberOfArguments(method) - 2
        print("numberOfArguments: \(numberOfArguments)")

        for j in 2 ..< Int(numberOfArguments) + 2 {
            method_getArgumentType(method, UInt32(j), ctype, maxChars)
            print("argumentType: \(String(cString: ctype))")
        }

        print()
    }

    free(methodList)

    return selectors
}

let myStruct = MyStruct()

myStruct.method0()
myStruct.method1("check")
myStruct.method2(0, 1.0)
myStruct.method3(arg1: 0, arg2: 1.0)

print("---\n")

let methods = getMethods()

myStruct.chosenMethod = { $0.method2(0, 1.0) }
//myStruct.chosenMethod = { $0.methods[1](0, 1.0) }
myStruct.execute()
```

Comment: Well, I need your advice, it's either array of String or Selector. For example: [..."method2(Int, Double)", "method3(arg1: Int, arg2: Double)"]. Something that is user-friendly and possible to call later...

Comment: Certainly, it's not. But this methods do work on swift https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime. I get everything using class_copyMethodList, method_getName, method_getNumberOfArguments, method_getArgumentType (I still need to do some stuff manually), but I don't know how to call the method. When we use addTarget method in iOS & #selector with method name - this works. So, why do you think it's impossible? And if it is, what's the alternative?

Comment: I think I’ve got what you mean. That is why I write @objc before extension and/or func that I want to use. And that is great, because swift funcs are not in the method list of MyClass that I want to get. And yes, I just want to describe & call.